# Can we add multiple teams in single Apple Enterprise account?

Tags: ios, enterprise

Can we add multiple teams in one Apple Enterprise account?

For example I have apple developer enterprise account for  **ABC** company and I publish ***Abc1*** app from this account.

So Now I want to publish ***Xyz1*** app from the same apple enterprise account, but the company name will be different?

Can we do this scenario using one Apple developer Enterprise account?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming

Comment: I think this belongs on Ask Different

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question which should be asked of the Customer Service department for the company you are dealing with. Please see: [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746) and [Why we're not customer support for \[your favorite company\]](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Apple Enterprise Programm is intended for developing apps for your enterprise (company) only. Publishing apps to non company people is a misuse of the enterprise program. If Apple is aware of that misuse they may revoke your certificates. I'm not sure how Apple handle this exactly.

e.g. If you work for a car producer you can use the enterprise program to develop an app for your management people to calculate internal production costs or manage internal working processes.

Your case is different. I think your company develops apps for other companies like B2B. There are two ways for that.

1. Get an Enterprise Account for each company or use their existing
   enterprise account (directly or let them resign and publish the app). Note: As I know a company can only have one enterprise account! When order the account you have to tell apple the DUNS number that unique identifies your company.
2. Use the Volume Purchase Program that publish the apps via App Store without showing it to everyone. see: [Volume Purchase Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/volume/b2b/)